# Get dynamic time and timeout after certain amount of time

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I am implementing an online exam portal, so that a user can start the mockup test(exam) and choose the anwsers for each question and proceed to the next question. 
Rules for the exam is to give 100question to complete in 75mins. 
So I need my back-end code to check each bit of time and track if the current_time not exceed 75min from the Exam_Start_time

How is this possible.

I made it like this for time being
$Start_time
$Current_time
and then check the difference on each page refresh and redirect if 75min limit exceed

But I think its not the better way and if we can trace it dynamically and redirect when the 75min mark reaches to the process the exam result it would be great.

Can any one help me in this context,
Is there a way if its not possible with PHP, HTML to use Javascript to achieve this

Hope to hear from you stacker.....thanks in advances

Comment: I would suggest against using javascript to do such checks, cause people can disable javascript, if the variables are known they can be updated through firebug/developer tools. I would go your way where i save the start time of test in database and before submitting the next answer, check it against the current time.

Comment: Same as Wiz: You should definitely NOT use JavaScript for this purpose. Not only, because it can be turned off, but also, because it is relying on LOCAL clock, which can be shifted anytime very easily. You need to rely on server side and back it up with a database. You web page must sent (either as URL or directly as AJAX call) an unique identifier and start time, which will be stored in database. Then, upon each periodic refresh another call should be made to check against current time that has left for particular identifier. Hope, this quick idea will help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions made. I am also think that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store in your database time and some unique id for each user. While user take a test send ajax request with some interval (i.e per minute) to the server with user unique id and check is everything ok with time if not redirect him to another page or block old one with javascript. But think about security, some user can guess and send another's id :)

If user disable javascript there is another scenario. Server closes tests which hasn't been  updated for some interval. And also about local time and javascript you haven't to send user's time to server because you have start time in database.

@trejder and @Wiz if think as you do it's better to do not use javascript at all as it can be turned off and request variables can be falsified by user.

Comment: Hello @Ruben; I am totally a newbie if you ask me to go with some ajax coding into the code and check the values in frequent intervals of time. Can you suggest a sample strip of code if it help me to incorporate into my code with php

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930975/how-do-i-make-ajax-calls-at-intervals-without-overlap)